# Tiling a $4 \times 4$ square with two corners removed using $ 2\times 1$ tiles.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

> Each of the squares in the following figure are $1m \times 1m$. The figure below needs to be tiled using $2m \times 1m$ tiles. The squares marked $X$ should not be tiled. Is such a tiling possible?

[image]

After extensive trial and error experiments I have come to the conclusion that such a tiling is not possible. Is that true? And if so how would one go about proving such a thing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen this in context of a checkerboard

Comment: You mean $2\times 1$ tiles right and not $2m\times 1m$? Also $m$ should definitely be even, otherwise it's surely impossible.

Comment: @bof oops ... noted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a tiling is not possible. To see this, color the square like a chessboard. The upper left and lower right corners have the same color (provided $m$ is even, but otherwise it's trivial), but each $2\times 1$ tile covers exactly one black and one white tile.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case of a tiling proof which is easy by colouring. If the squares are coloured as a checkerboard, consider how many black and white squares you have. And what can you say about the $2\times 1$ tiles in terms of colours?

Although this seems very simple, it can be quite delicate to get the right tiling for a particular case - and in some cases more than two colours come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

The clever coloring argument works for squares of any size. However, for the $4\times4$ case, "trial and error" works fine.

First consider the upper right square d4. It must be covered by a horizontal or a vertical tile. By symmetry (the whole figure is symmetric about the diagonal from upper right to lower left), we may assume a horizontal tile, covering the squares {c4,d4}.

Next, the remaining top-row square b4 must be covered by a vertical tile {b3,b4}.

Next, a3 must be covered by a vertical tile {a2,a3}.

Next, the lower left square a1 must be covered by a horizontal time {a1,b1}.

Next, c1 must be covered by a vertical tile {c1,c2}.

But now there is no way to cover b2.